# How to run tslint using Angular Cli?

Tags: angular, npm, tslint

I am facing issue when I am trying to run tslint from Angular Cli.

*> ng lint*

Error

> Failed to load E:\Projects\lsp-ui\node_modules\ng2-slimscroll\tslint.json: Could not find custom rule directory: E:\Projects\lsp-ui\node_modules\ng2-slimscroll\node_modules\codelyzer

[Error while running]

[image]

Comment: You are missing `codelyzer` in your `node_modules`. Did you install the dependencies (with `npm install`)?

Comment: Yes i did. But still its is giving same error

Comment: Try to check the versions of nodeJS, angular / angular-cli and VSC. If anything try to uninstall and re-install with all the latest versions.

Answer (score 0):

Run `npm install` or `npm install codelyzer` first.

Also check the file path of `tsconfig.json` in the Angular Cli configuration lint section, the configuration of rules directory in tslint.json, such as:

```
"rulesDirectory": [
        "../node_modules/codelyzer"
    ]
```

Comment: I'm not sure about this. Angular is supposed to install codelyzer: the "ng new" command is supposed to do all the installs

Answer (score 0):

Here is official guide for you.

> Codelyzer should work out of the box with Atom but for VSCode you will
>   have to open Code > Preferences > User Settings, and enter the
>   following config:
>
> {   "tslint.rulesDirectory": "./node_modules/codelyzer",
>   "typescript.tsdk": "node_modules/typescript/lib" }

https://github.com/mgechev/codelyzer#editor-configuration